# Foreign Key constraints in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I have a database scheme with versioning data rows, e.g.
Table `Person` has the columns

```
id (int, PK)
name (String)
current (Bool)
firstid (int)
```

`Current` is 0 for previous data, 1 for the latest entry. All rows for the same entity have the same `FirstID`, which points to the first `ID` of the set.

Referencing table: `Adress` with the same principle:

```
id (int, PK)
street (String)
person_id (int)
current (Bool)
firstid (int)
```

`Person_id` points to `patient.firstid`. So `firstid` is never unique, only if `current=1`

My problem is: I would like to add referential integrity to my tables, but this only works, if the referenced column (`patient.firstid`) is unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at refactoring your table structure. But to keep within the current structure, add a self-referencing foreign key to person

firstid references person(id)

Then, reference the "base person" from the address table

address.person_id references person(id)  -- which should ONLY store a link to the first id

Answer (score 0):

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have
>   to be linked only to a PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint in another table; it can
>   also be defined to reference the
>   columns of a UNIQUE constraint in
>   another table. A FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint can contain null values;
>   however, if any column of a composite
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint contains null
>   values, then verification of the
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint will be skipped.

Data from two related tables can be combined even if no PRIMARY KEY or FOREIGN KEY constraints are defined between the tables, but a foreign key relationship between two tables indicates that the two tables have been optimized to be combined in a query that uses the keys as its criteria.

reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933117(v=sql.80).aspx